# How to retrieve a moved pointer to a function that runs on a separate thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++14, move, unique-ptr

How can I retrieve the `std::unique_ptr` pointer that has been moved into a function when that function runs on a separate thread?

Consider the following example:

```
using IntPtr = std::unique_ptr<int>;

IntPtr&& update(IntPtr &&fp_)
{
    *fp_ = 23;
    return std::move(fp_);
}

int main()
{
    IntPtr foo_ptr = std::make_unique<int>(0);
    foo_ptr = update(std::move(foo_ptr));
    std::cout<< "data: " << *foo_ptr <<std::endl;
}
```

This is fine. `foo_ptr` is moved into `fp_` on the `update()` and then retrieved (moved back) to the `foo_ptr`.

How can I retrieve the `foo_ptr` if `update()` was running on a separate thread???

```
using IntPtr = std::unique_ptr<int>;

IntPtr&& update(IntPtr &&fp_)
{
    *fp_ = 23;
    return std::move(fp_);
}

int main()
{
    IntPtr foo_ptr = std::make_unique<int>(0);
    std::thread foo_thread(update,std::move(foo_ptr));
    foo_thread.join();
    std::cout<< "data: " << *foo_ptr <<std::endl; // SEGFAULT because foo_ptr is a nullptr.
}
```

Online code example: https://rextester.com/MQDVU97718

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't.

You gave ownership of the memory to another thread. That thread now owns that memory and will delete it when it terminates. It doesn't exist after `join`, and you never moved the pointer back to the main thread.

If you want a thread to fill in some data for another thread, then either you need to use shared ownership or the producing thread should not own the memory at all (ie: you pass a raw pointer).

Or just use a `packaged_task<int(int)>`, and you don't have to (directly) allocate memory at all:

```
int update(int value)
{
    return 23;
}

int main()
{
    int value = 0;
    std::packaged_task<int(int)> task(update);
    auto future_int = task.get_future();

    std::thread foo_thread(std::move(task), value);
    foo_thread.join();
    std::cout<< "data: " << future_int.get() <<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I thought `join()` tells the main thread to wait for the other thread to finish. Then it clears up the memory associated with that thread. But I didn't realise you wouldn't get your value back! In that case, I could dereference the pointer and pass it's underlying data by reference to the function using `std::ref`. Would that work?

Comment: @ConstantinosGlynos: "*I thought join() tells the main thread to wait for the other thread to finish.*" It does. "Finish" means that the thread is over, including destroying any objects that thread created. Such as the `unique_ptr` parameter you gave it. But why not just use packaged task and stop fiddling around with allocating memory?

Comment: @NicolBolas This question is basically asking how to return an object from a thread. Your solution appears to indicate that it is impossible, which is not true.

Comment: @user253751: `promise/future` is the standard way of returning an object from a thread. The return value of the thread function is discarded. Yes, you can use output parameters or other such techniques, but a `packaged_task` is the best means of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to just use a wrapper function that writes the result back to `foo_ptr`:

```
std::thread foo_thread([&foo_ptr]() {
    foo_ptr = update(std::move(foo_ptr));
});

foo_thread.join();
std::cout<< "data: " << *foo_ptr <<std::endl;
```

Note though that between the `std::thread` constructor call and the completion of the `join()` call, the main thread must not access `foo_ptr` in any way. Doing so would be a data race. Before the constructor and after `join` this is fine, as both of these calls serve as synchronization points, but any access in between would be unsynchronized and race with the write to `foo_ptr` inside the lambda.

If this sounds too dangerous, consider an approach where the thread puts the result into a `std::promise` and the main thread then retrieves the object from a corresponding `std::future`:

```
std::promise<IntPtr> p;
std::future<IntPtr> fut = p.get_future();
std::thread foo_thread([ptr = std::move(foo_ptr), p = std::move(p)]() mutable {
    p.set_value(update(std::move(ptr)));
});

foo_ptr = std::move(fut.get());
```

Comment: Thanks! Since I'm moving the ptr and therefore it is a nullptr, how come there would be a race condition if it is accessed by the main thread before the `join()`? The memory has been moved on to the function `fp_`. If the main thread accesses `foo_ptr` after it's been moved, then it's ill-formed and hopefully the compiler can catch it before run-time.

Comment: @ConstantinosGlynos The race condition is on the access to the smart pointer object `foo_ptr`, not on the memory that it refers to. In the first example, the thread is making changes to that smart pointer object (which is still alive on the stack of the main thread, despite its value being `nullptr`) in-place, and that's what is causing the race. The second example does not have this problem because it leaves the object alone and instead move-constructs a new smart pointer for the thread to work on.

Comment: AAhhh I see. Thank you for the explanation. Sorry, I'm still very new to multi-threading.

Comment: @ConstantinosGlynos No worries. I still remember the headaches it caused me when I first got my feet wet with threading, so rest assured that being confused about this at first is not unusual at all.